# Meteor: [Load Order] Make JavaScript file load after HTML file is loaded?

Tags: meteor

### Load Order Issues

I am having trouble making Meteor load my JavaScript ***after*** my HTML file  fully loads when I go to localhost:3000. The problem is that my JavaScript keeps loading ***before*** my HTML file, and makes the page look unloaded when I use stuff like `alert();` or `prompt();`. I've tried a lot of solutions such as naming my JavaScript file as main.js and putting my HTML file in a deeper directory and using `<script>` tags. I have also read the documentation concerning this: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp Solutions I've tired based off the documentation such as putting files in `client/lib` , `client/compatibility` , and `lib` have proven to no avail. I also tired `Meteor.startup`and I placed the file for it in the `client` folder. *(The code inside it):*

```
Meteor.startup( function () {
  $.get("client/lib/testproject.html")
  $.getScript("client/testproject.js");
});
```

The above *sort of* solved my problem, but it loaded the JavaScript file **two times**. The first time was *before* the HTML loaded and the second time was *after* the HTML loaded. I don't know a way to prevent the first JS load from happening when using `Meteor.startup`, so any solutions for that are also appreciated.
The **JavaScript file's code** I am referring to is simple. *(In it's entirety)*:

```
prompt("Hello World!"); 
myList = ["apples", "oranges", "bananas"];
myList.forEach(function(value, index) {
  alert('I have ' + value + ' for dinner.');
});
```

### Summary

To summarize my problem:

- My Problem:

  1. Go to localhost
  2. JavaScript loads *first*
  3. HTML loads *second*
- What I Need:

  1. Go to localhost
  2. HTML loads *first*
  3. JavaScript loads *second*

**The Question:** How can I make my JavaScript load only after when my HTML is loaded? And how can I restructure my folder, file-names, and/or code to make it behave as I want it to in this case?

- *Since the code posted is extremely simple to reproduce I kindly ask that you
  run your own solution with a setup similar to what I have and not something that uses a million packages since that is unnecessary for my case, on Meteor, before responding to this.*
- *I'm on Meteor 1.1.0.2*

**Here is a link to my folder structure with included HTML code along with filenames I used:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GLT3.png

Comment: Really recommend you follow a tutorial like the Discover Meteor book since it's fairly obvious you need some foundation on at least template callbacks in Meteor. - http://www.discovermeteor.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a decisive information : you should wrap your Javascript code into a `Template.yourTemplate.rendered=function () {}` function.

That is the meteor way to ensure that your related html code is properly rendered first.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Meteor will always repackage your files and load them automatically in a specific order ([Meteor structuring your app](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)). First files in `client/compatibility` then `client/lib` and then the others JS files.

You should also rewrite your code so it does not get executed immediately at load time, like wrapping everything in a function. And then, you should call this code when the DOM is loaded, which does not necessarily mean in `Meteor.startup` but also in [`onRendered` callbacks](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) in your templates.

Comment: No, this does not happen, I'm stuck at this right now and it isn't working like that, from what I see it loads client/lib first and then client/compatibility which is completely wrong - per what they are writing in the documentation -